# Python3.x в запросе get через браузер отсылается разное время откуда это время можно взять?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, requests, datetime

**1636977890333** из чего это время получается

максимум что я смог найти это в скрипте js вот это

```
a.open("GET", "".concat("/название сайта").concat(e, "?time=").concat(Date.now()), !0),
   a.timeout = 1e4,
   a.send(),
   setTimeout(c, 1e4, !0)
  }
))
```

p.s: если не поменять время то выдаёт ошибку {error: 1}

[image: 1636977890333 нужно узнать откуда происходит это время]

Comment: Аналог в питоне `int(time.time() * 1000)`

Comment: @andreymal вы можете написать это в ответе и я приму это как правильный ответ.